# React-native facebook login crash on Android

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I'm using react-native facebook login through this library: [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk). Following the installation guide did not completely get it working, but I managed to get it working after modifications on the native side, as instructed in many github issues etc.

Anyways, it was working fine two weeks ago, but now, when I try to login with facebook, the application immediately crashes. It doesn't open any login page or do anything else.

What is weird is that if I open a browser in the emulator, leave it to background, and then try to login, the login goes further (I get to actually login, but when I'm directed back, the application crashes).

From the tombstone files I am able to get following warnings/messages:

1. > Expected native library version number "",actual native library
   >   version number ""
2. Tens like these:

> Could not find generated setter for class
>   com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBLoginButtonManager

How could I solve this problem? And why it doesn't work anymore? I didn't change anything in the code. Only thing I can think of is that it loads something from the internet during compiling the application. How could it otherwise fail?

Comment: have you check your FB client ID & FB client secret?

Comment: Yes, they are correct

Comment: i think that is because the mismatch version between SDK you use and SDK on your dashboard. Can you check the SDK version you use and the one that appear on your dashboard?

Comment: What do you mean by SDK on my dashboard? What is a dashboard? Also, check my answer, I got it working again.

Comment: sorry i mean the API version, seems like its not what happened in your case. Glad you can solve it. maybe you have to try this on real device also. I think this can be a huge problem if this happen after release

Comment: please let me know about the progress for this problem also, because i'm working on similar stuff. good luck with your project

Comment: From android studio, it shows that installed API version is 23. But I don't know if you actually specify the api that you use in the app? In Android manifest, you set the minimun, and the target. But I don't know if those values are really used by your app in anyway? I thought they are just info for play store, that can you download the app or not. Also through them the system can trigger some sort of compatibility modes if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, it seems working ok right now. Somewhere I read that changing from the default google emulator to genymotion emulator might solve lot of these emulator related problems. Think I will give it a try some day.

Comment: not the android version, i mean the facebook graph api version, i believe it should be handled by the SDK on react-native. I don't really know about this actually, but it seems like not what happened with your case. Yeah i use genymotion also, never encounter this error. Maybe it's simply because of the emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer for how I solved the problem, not that much about why it was behaving like this.

In short:

I got it working again by **updating the emulator and android API 6.0 through Android Studio**.

```
<Rant state='begin'>
```

I have no idea why this worked, nor why did it broke in the first place. As it was working good with the old emulator and API 6.0 earlier.

It seems like the react-native fbsdk is far from stable. Or then it is completely react-native's fault, idk to be honest. But this just makes me want to develop fully native, instead of react-native, which seems unstable from my experience so far.

```
<Rant state='end'>
```